# Why won't border-radius apply to my images?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

G'day, I have an ID called #img in my style sheet where I have written border-radius: 15px; in my html I have assigned the id to a div . However, this does not border radius my images. if I use the img selector it Applys it to all images, i dont want the logo or the first image to be radiused.

heres my code:

```css
body {
  margin: auto;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background-image: url('assets/bg800bulbs.jpg');
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  text-align: center;
}

#page {
  width: 960px;
  height: 3210px;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

#menu {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  width: 30%;
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

#logo {
  float: left;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

#text {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 50px;
  margin-right: 50px;
  text-align: left;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

hr {
  width: 860px;
  margin-left: 0px;
}

#texta {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 50px;
  margin-right: 50px;
  text-align: left;
}

#img {
  display: block;
  float: right;
  margin: 0px 0px 15px 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  margin-right: 50px;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

#pad {
  padding-top: 50px;
}

#pad2 {
  padding-top: 100px;
}

#text2 {
  text-align: right;
  padding-top: 20PX;
  padding-right: 20PX;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 300;
}

#page2 {
  width: 800px;
  height: 250px;
  border: rgb(79, 229, 240);
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  margin-top: -20px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  background-color: #d4d4d4;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

#test {
  padding-top: 10px;
  ;
  float: left;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: #79d5ff;
}

#hrs {
  width: 960px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-left: -50px;
  margin-top: 130px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  background-color: #e78c1d;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
}

#pad3 {
  padding-top: 10px;
}

#textb {
  color: #d4d4d4;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  padding-top: 1px;
}

#button {
  background-color: #c4c1c1;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-top: 125px;
  margin-left: 300px;
  border-color: black;
}

#btext1 {
  margin-left: 60px;
  padding-top: 2px;
}

#button2 {
  display: block;
  background-color: #efeded;
  width: 300px;
  height: 30px;
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin-left: 280px;
  border: black;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

#btext2 {
  margin-left: 100px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

#marg {
  margin-right: 50px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
  <link href='stylesheet.css' rel='stylesheet'>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="page">

    <table id="menu">
      <tr>
        <div id="logo">
          <div id="Top"></div>
          <image src="assets/logo32.png"></image>
        </div>

        <td><a href="#AB" , style="color: black; text-decoration: none;" ;>About Us</a></td>
        <td><a href="#T" , style="text-decoration: none; color: black;" ;>Testimonials</a></td>

      </tr>
    </table>

    <div>
      <image src="assets/htgreen-hero.jpg"></image>
    </div>

    <div id="text">

      <h2>Towards a zero electricity bill</h2>

      <div>
        <hr>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div id="text">

      <p>Sick of getting big power bills? You've replaced all the old bulbs with LEDs, got a new fridge and super-efficient heat pump and youre still paying around $1200 a year? Your next step is to let HT Green work with you to design and install a system
        that uses solar, wind or geothermal that's guaranteed to wipe that power bill for now and into the future.</p>

    </div>

    <div id="texta">
      <div id="pad">
        <h3> Solar PV solutions</h3>
      </div>
      <div>
        <hr>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="texta">

      <p>
        <div id="img">
          <image src="assets/pv250.jpg"></image>
        </div>
        Solar Photovoltaic systems have come of age. Installers now can guarantee reliable cost-free power to your home or business. ROI is now taking less time than ever thanks to the ever decreasing equipment costs and better technology.
      </p>



      <p>If you have battery storage such as a Tesla Powerwall or similar Lithium Ion chemistry solutions then you can take your savings even further.</p>



      <p>Call us now to discuss which solution is the best fit for your home. </p>

      <div id="pad2">
        <h3> Geothermal</h3>
      </div>
      <div>
        <hr>
      </div>


      <p>
        <div id="img">
          <image src="assets/geo250.jpg"></image>
        </div> Energy from the earth. It sounds simple because it is. The earth is warmer than the air and we can use this to heat your home. HT Green can engineer a solution to fit your situation to give you free plentiful home warming energy year-round.</p>

      <p>Geothermal power is cost effective, reliable, and environmentally friendly, but has previously been geographically limited to areas near tectonic plate boundaries. Recent technological advances have dramatically expanded the range and size of viable
        resources, especially for direct applications such as home heating.</p>
      <p>
        Geothermal wells tend to release greenhouse gases trapped deep within the earth, but these emissions are much lower than those of conventional fossil fuels. As a result, geothermal power has the potential to help mitigate global warming if widely deployed
        instead of fossil fuels.
      </p>


      <div id="pad">
        <h3> Wind Turbines </h3>
      </div>
      <div>
        <hr>
      </div>


      <p>
        <div id="img">
          <image src="assets/turbine250.jpg"></image>
        </div>
        If you have the space and the aspect, we have the know-how to engineer a wind turbine system that generates electricity when the wind blows. Team a wind turbine with a solar PV system and you increase your energy generation potential..
      </p>

      <p>New to wind power? HT Green can show you more about how a wind turbine works, the benefits of wind energy and how a wind turbine is installed.</p>
      <p>
        If you're not sure on the type of turbine you need, before you buy from us, contact one of our wind power experts for the right advice.
      </p>


      <div id="pad">
        <h3 id="AB"> About Us </h3>
      </div>
      <div>
        <hr>
      </div>

      <div id="marg">

        <p> HT Green was established in 1997. We specialise in green technologies such as solar, wind turbines, geothermal and now small-scale hydro plants.</p>

        <p>Company Directors Robert and Janet Wilkins built HT Green from the ground up with a small business grant and big dreams to power homes and businesses with energy derived from natural sources.</p>

      </div>

      <div id="button2">
        <div id="btext2">
          <p><a href="#Top" , style="color: black; text-decoration: none;" ;>Back to Top</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>


      <div id="pad2">
        <h3 id="T"> Testimonials</h3>
      </div>


      <div id="pad">
        <div id="page2">
          <div id="text2">

            <p>
              <div id="test">
                <image src="assets/testimonials/j-g-brown-200.jpg"></image>
              </div>
              "We installed our solar panels last year and our electricity bill is now less than zero. We actually went into credit in late Spring!"
              <strong>June & Gavin Brown, Surrey Hills NSW</strong>
            </p>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div id="pad3">
        <div id="page2">
          <div id="text2">

            <p>
              <div id="test">
                <image src="assets/testimonials/s-p-hill-200.jpg"></image>
              </div>
              "We toyed with the idea of installing a hydro system a while back and never got around to it but thanks to HT Green's Hydro Oasis System it was easy! Our creek supplies our total energy needs."
              <strong>Sandra & Peter Hill, Adelaide SA. </strong>
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>


      <div id="pad3">
        <div id="page2">
          <div id="text2">

            <p>
              <div id="test">
                <image src="assets/testimonials/r-sanderson-200.jpg"></image>
              </div>
              "I can look forward to no more electricity bills! HT Green took care of everything; recommended!" <strong>
                            Roberta Sanderson, TAS </strong>
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div id="button2">
        <div id="btext2">
          <p><a href="#Top" , style="color: black; text-decoration: none;">Back to Top</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div id="hrs">
        <div id="textb">
          <p> <strong>Copyright © 2022</strong> </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: _"However, this does not border radius my images."_ - well of course it doesn't, you targeted the div with your selector, and not the image inside of it. And `<image src="...."></image>` is not even proper HTML - the correct tag name is `img`, and it is a self-closing element. So fix that first, and then use `#img img` as selector.

Comment: @CBroe what do you mean, probably should have added I'm a beginner.

Comment: What is unclear? `<image src="assets/pv250.jpg"></image>` should be just `<img src="assets/pv250.jpg">` in the first place. And what selector to use, I just very explicitly told you.

Comment: @CBroe, so this should work?       <div id="img">
                <img src="assets/pv250.jpg">
            </div>

Comment: If you use the selector I told you in your rule.

Comment: yeah, nah still don't understand what you mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are selecting the wrapping element and not the image itself.

Replace:

```
#img{

display:block;
float: right;
margin: 0px 0px 15px 20px;
padding: 10px;
border-radius: 5px;
background-color: #FFFFFF;
margin-right: 50px;
border-radius: 15px;

}
```

With:

```
#img img{

display:block;
float: right;
margin: 0px 0px 15px 20px;
padding: 10px;
border-radius: 5px;
background-color: #FFFFFF;
margin-right: 50px;
border-radius: 15px;

}
```

Notice how we target the actual image and not the wrapping element.